# Flot Graph is not getting populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I had found related answers to mt question but not works in my case . I am usin Flot to plot graph .
             var qwer = []; data = [[qwer]];  $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);

qwer is having this value
            [1361451916000,36.862274],[1361451915000,1000.664185],[1361451915000,33.470932],[1361451915000,0.331087],[1361451915000,3.854041],[1361451915000,2.084494],[1361451915000,622.265259],[1361451915000,167.02771],[1361451853000,1000.628418],[1361451853000,33.482491],[1361451853000,0.34266],[1361451853000,3.781773],[1361451853000,2.14386],[1361451853000,625.780762],[1361451853000,166.767822],[1361451853000,36.863419],[1361451793000,1000.501465],[1361451793000,33.446846],[1361451793000,0.339476],[1361451793000,3.729937],[1361451793000,2.390623],[1361451793000,622.265259],[1361451793000,167.497406],[1361451793000,36.860085],[1361451733000,33.503113],[1361451733000,0.352068],[1361451733000,3.797665],[1361451733000,2.168059],[1361451733000,631.054565],[1361451733000,167.291168],[1361451733000,36.847496],[1361451732000,1000.508667],[1361451673000,634.570068],[1361451673000,167.753693],[1361451673000,36.867523],[1361451672000,1000.680298],[1361451672000,33.4543],[1361451672000,0.34401],[1361451672000,3.687938],[1361451672000,2.069354],[1361451617000,634.570068],[1361451617000,166.691528],[1361451617000,36.854553],[1361451616000,1000.682129],[1361451616000,33.429085],[1361451616000,0.352169],[1361451616000,3.652372],[1361451616000,2.104402],[1361451616000,2749.431641],[1361451616000,26.239849]

But its not plotting my graph . 
while if is use           data = [[[1361451915000, 100], [1361451853000, 200], [1361451793000, 500], [1361451733000, 300]]];

it works fine for me . What could be the possible cause .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think there must be something about your code that's missing in the question; can you create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping your var qwer with an additional set of brackets:

```
qwer =  [[1361451916000,36.862274],[1361451915000,1000.664185],[1361451915000,33.470932]]
```

then push that dataset to the var data

```
data.push(qwer)
```

have a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/KMTjZ/1/